# Azure Storage Account --> Shared Access Signature Error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

What is this complaining about?

I don't understand the error message?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your storage account using SAS in Storage Explorer?

Comment: This error is telling you that you need to include a blob container name in your SAS URL. So your SAS URL should be something like `https://account.core.windows.net/blob-container-name?sas-token-parameters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I agree with *@Gaurav Mantri*, you missed including **blob container
> name** in SAS URL that is giving you that error.

I have one storage account with blob container named **`sri`** like below:

[image]

When I tried to connect via **Azure Storage Explorer** without including blob container name in SAS URL, I got **same error** like this:

```
https://<storage_acc_name>.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=c&sp=rwdlacupyx&se=2023-06-13T13:17:29Z&st=2023-06-13T05:17:29Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[image]

To resolve it, you need to include **blob container name** in SAS URL like below:

```
https://<storage_acc_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<blob_container_name>?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=c&sp=rwdlacupyx&se=2023-06-13T13:17:29Z&st=2023-06-13T05:17:29Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

[image]

After selecting *Next*, click on **`Connect`** option to access blob container like this:

[image]

Now, I am able to access files in blob storage container successfully via **Azure Storage Explorer** like below:

[image]